# android BaseGamesUtils library error

Tags: android, radix

I'm trying to implement the google play services in my app. I have successfully imported BaseGameUtils library from GitHub, referenced the GooglePlayServicesLib to the library, but it has a really annoying error...

This is part of the GameHelper.java file :

```
import com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateManager;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesActivityResultCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Invitation;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Multiplayer;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased.TurnBasedMatch;
import com.google.android.gms.games.request.GameRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
```

Everything is OK except the `import com.google.android.gms.games.request.GameRequest;` line which is underlined with the error message : `com.google.android.gms.games.request cannot be resolved`

I have no idea about how to solve this problem, and I see that the help community around google play games services is not as large as I would have bet...

any help would be welcome ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. What fixed it for me was updating the google play-services library to a newer version.

Update the google play services library to the latest version. Thanks

Comment: I've looked at it, but everything looks like being up to date :/ oh, mabe the imported project isn't. Shall I delete/re-import it in eclipse ?

Comment: Yes! You'd have to delete and re-import if it isn't linked to the original path (sdks\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib). Thus, if you copied to workspace whilst importing

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem ! I ran into another one (R.java file was imported creating an error) I just had to delete the new one.